# 'rake db:drop' does not work

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using **Rails v2.3.2** with **MySQL v5.1** and **mysql2** gem.

I run the following rake tasks in a method like:

```
def db_operation
    Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke #this one does not work
    Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    ...
 end
```

**but** `Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke` does not drop my database**, and there is **no** error message which makes me have no clue to find the reason.

Then:
  I go to **MySQL command-line** to execute "`DROP DATABASE my_db;`" , it raise me the following error message:

```
ERROR 1010 (HY000): Error dropping database (can't rmdir './my_db/', errno: 17)
```

After that:
  I run above code again, **the database surprisingly get dropped...**

What was happening?? Why my `rake db:drop` does not drop database, but after I run drop command on MySQL command-line and run rake db:drop again, it get dropped??? (and I got error when I run on MySQL command-line)

**P.S.**

`rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` are working without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25783/error-dropping-database-in-mysql-5-1-on-ubuntu)

you might be having files in /var/lib/mysql/my_db/ that mysql didn't create.
Try listing those files and see what's there. Try moving anything there to a temporary directory (or deleting if you're really sure you won't need them), then try again.